# how to fix console error in magento 2.2.6?

Tags: magento2.2.6

How to fix `jquery` console error in `magento2.2.6`?
please check attached screenshot http://prntscr.com/ld1s8k.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this error is related to some `requirejs.config.js` file. You have used jQuery in some file and that js files is incorrectly mapped or being called before the jquery js file

Comment: yes i include bootstrap.min.css, jquery.min.js and bootstrap.min.js in our custom theme "web/css" folder, then please let me know what i do in [requirejs.config.js] file.

Comment: jquery is added by default in magento2, you dont need that